Why does the AMBA APB bus need a PENABLE signal?
What is the purpose of the PENABLE signal of the APB bus?
I understand that PENABLE signals that an address has been set on the PADDR bus. But, there are PSEL and PCLK lines. If the PSEL is set and the PCLK rising the PADDR is valid, isn't it?
May be the PENABLE is needed to separate the address setting from the data setting. For what? And even so, it can be done with the PCLK only.
May be the PENABLE needed to separate pieces of data from each other? But it can be done with the PSEL only.
Why does the AMBA APB bus need a PENABLE signal?

The AMBA APB is designed as a finite state machine with 3 states:

IDLE
SETUP
ACCESS

PENABLE is 0 during the IDLE and SETUP states; it is 1 during the ACCESS state.
The SETUP state lasts for one clock cycle, and its purpose is to allow the APB slave time to respond to an APB master access request.
Refer to Chapter 3 Operating States in the APB spec.

Diagram source

The question is "Why does the AMBA APB bus need a PENABLE signal?"
The answer is "The APB needs the PENABLE line for..."

In other words, the AMBA standard introduces the PENABLE line into the APB bus to satisfy the AMBA standard. Ok.

If the engine of this site would allow you to vote separately for the correction of questions (+1) and for your answer (-1), I would do so.
Now I believe that your answer does not answer the question posed. Your "answer" is more of a paraphrase of the AMBA standard. I, of course, read the AMBA standard before asking the question.
